# How to open .ccproj in VS2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, azure, cloud

How to open .ccproj projects types in VS2010, ccproj file type is a Cloud project i suppose.

Please provide inputs.

Comment: Make sure that you have Windows Azure SDK installed.

Answer (score 19):

The link above is good but points to a specific version of the SDK. As such, it is subject to obsolescence. The following seems to be a generic page for the Azure SDK, which should not be bind to a specific version:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/

You can get from there a link to the latest download (button "Get the SDK").

Answer (score 7):

Download and install [Windows Azure SDK and Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio (March 2011)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15658)